# Installed MacOSX over HDD containing wallet

Tags: wallet-recovery

I formatted and re installed MacOSX on the HDD that contained my `wallet.dat`. I have no backup of it.

Any ideas how I could possibly recover this file and my Bitcoins?

Comment: You can try recovery tools (like this one : http://www.prosofteng.com/products/data_rescue.php) by I think that this is too late.

Comment: mmmh are you sure you haven't [already asked](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9760/help-how-can-i-find-my-bitcoin-iwallet) this?

Comment: Yes. Your linked thread is, clearly, from another user.

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience and I think you would be mightily lucky if you succeed in recovering your wallet file, but I'd advise you to stop using that HDD (to avoid too much writes) and try [googling for the problem and trying all the proposed solutions](https://www.google.com/search?q=restore%20hdd%20after%20reformat).