# How can I find my bitcoin wallet?

Tags: lost-wallet

I had to update the software on my computer and had to delete everything on my computer. I wasn't aware that my Bitcoin wallet was like a physical wallet. I thought I'd be able to download the wallet and enter my address into it and get everything back. I don't know what to do. I'm freaking out and don't know how and if I can get my Bitcoin wallet back. I know the address of my wallet but I don't have any of the files on my computer.

Comment: TL;DR if you have lost your `wallet.dat`, there is nothing you can do. Try with some recovery software, such as [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately once you lose your wallet, there is no way of getting it back.

The wallet is so inportant because it contains your **private key**, this key is used to send money from your wallet to other people. Without it you can't do anything.

Next time consider writing down the private key and keep it locked up, or keep an offline version of your wallet.dat file. however be careful with keeping online versions, since anyone who has your private key can send money anywhere.

Just for clarity, you talk about your 'adress', is this your public or your private key? With other words, did you use it to send money? Or to recieve money?